# How can I spawn a group of mobs within a certain radius?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to spawn multiple mobs within say, a 20x20 radius or so.
The coords are: -277, 94, -37 (the center)

All I have right now is:

`summon area_effect_cloud ~ ~-9 ~ {Passengers:[{id:zombie},{id:zombie}]}`

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to spawn mobs in random places?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158538/is-it-possible-to-spawn-mobs-in-random-places)