# How to summon Fireballs in random places with commands?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need to summon Fireballs in random places, but I can't figure out how. Any help?

Comment: What have you tried? We appreciate if you show some effort, instead of just asking.

Comment: Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229610/what-sources-of-randomness-can-be-made-with-commands-in-minecraft

Comment: @Hacker that's for [tag:minecraft-java-edition] and unlikely to be helpful in [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition].

Comment: While [this wiki article](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorials/Randomizers) doesn't explicitly answer your question, it could spark some ideas.

Comment: The bedrock edition equivalent of @Hacker's question is https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/377356/185203. But it's still not very useful here. Also, the same question has already been asked for Java Edition as https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/158538/185203. I'm not familiar enough with Bedrock Edition commands to determine whether its answer is relevant here.

Comment: @pppery yes, the same question for java edition is quite relevant here as well, as the bedrock system would work in a similar way to that top question, namely using spreadplayers. However the bedrock edition syntax for this command is slightly different, so I'd actually say there should be an independant answer allowed here.

Comment: Agreed. My position is that Java Edition questions are almost never duplicates of Bedrock Edition questions (or vice versa). But it's still helpful to link to otherwise identical questions for different editions, as an inspiration to potential answerers.